# my cmake can't bootstrap and i dont understand

Tags: cmake, bootstrapping

when install something like :cmake, sdl2_image, ...
after  dependency:

```
./bootstrap --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.28.3 --no-system-libs --parallel=4 --datadir=/share/cmake --docdir=/share/doc/cmake --mandir=/share/man --system-zlib --system-bzi
Last 15 lines from /Users/mac/Library/Logs/Homebrew/cmake/01.bootstrap:
-DCMake_BUILD_LTO=ON
```

i'm stuck.

i try to install gcc but it not work, too

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/optional:942:27: note: candidate function has been explicitly made unavailable
    constexpr value_type& value() &
                          ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/optional:933:33: note: candidate function has been explicitly made unavailable
    constexpr value_type const& value() const&
                                ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/optional:951:28: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'optional<...>' to 'optional<...>' for object argument
    constexpr value_type&& value() &&
                           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/optional:960:34: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'optional<...>' to 'const optional<...>' for object argument
    constexpr value_type const&& value() const&&
                                 ^
2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [isl_test_cpp17-checked.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [isl_test_cpp17.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: A little more detail regarding what steps you took would be helpful.